# How to configure Django VPS location in URL request

Tags: django

I am trying to configure my Django app (Djnago 3.05) to work from a server location.

The location is http://dev.apps.net/tac.

How do i include this in each request?

I managed to do this if adding in views.py the '/tac' prefix and add a folder named 'tac' in which all the templates exist.

myviews.py

```
@login_required
def item_list(request):
    meta = "V1.1"
    if not any(field in request.GET for field in set(UserFilter.get_fields())):
        user_list = item.objects.order_by("-date").all()[:50]
    else:
        user_list = item.objects.order_by("-date").all()
    user_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_list)
    return render(request, "tac/items/item_list.html", {"filter": user_filter})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r"^login/$",
        admin_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login.html"),
        name="login",
    ),
    url(r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"),
    url(r"^input/$", views.inputprocess, name="inputprocess"),
    url(r"^items/$", views.item_list, name="item_list"),
    url(r"^items/create/$", views.item_create, name="item_create"),
    url(r"^items/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$", views.item_update, name="item_update"),
    url(r"^items/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$", views.item_delete, name="item_delete"),
    url(r"^reports/$", views.reports, name="reports"),
    url(r"^timeline/$", views.timeline, name="timeline"),
    url(r"^support/$", views.support, name="support"),
    url(r"^dbToools/$", views.dbTools, name="dbTools"),
    url(r"^logout/$", views.logout_view, name="logout_view"),
    url(r"^upload/$", views.upload, name="upload"),
    path("accounts/login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view()),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way. How could I do this more efficient? Could you guys please help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using this config for urls.py (i found it in another post here)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r"^tac/",
        include(
            [
                url(
                    r"^login/$",
                    admin_views.LoginView.as_view(
                        template_name="registration/login.html"
                    ),
                    name="login",
                ),
                url(
                    r"^$", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"
                ),
                url(r"^input/$", views.inputprocess, name="inputprocess"),
                url(r"^items/$", views.item_list, name="item_list"),
                url(r"^items/create/$", views.item_create, name="item_create"),
                url(
                    r"^items/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$",
                    views.item_update,
                    name="item_update",
                ),
                url(
                    r"^items/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$",
                    views.item_delete,
                    name="item_delete",
                ),
                url(r"^reports/$", views.reports, name="reports"),
                url(r"^timeline/$", views.timeline, name="timeline"),
                url(r"^support/$", views.support, name="support"),
                url(r"^dbToools/$", views.dbTools, name="dbTools"),
                url(r"^logout/$", views.logout_view, name="logout_view"),
                url(r"^upload/$", views.upload, name="upload"),
                path("accounts/login/", auth_views.LoginView.as_view()),
                path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
            ]
        ),
    ),
]
```